# I am unable to clone the repo into git desktop

Tags: git-bash

When I input, git clone git@github.com:Ashe-EG/Prework-Study-Guide.git  .I get the errors
no such identity: /c/Users/User/.shh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I don't understand what I'm overlooking and would appreciate assistance.

- I have tried to re-copy the url ensuring it was the ssh variant.
- I have made sure I was in the desktop directory.

Comment: 1) That path should be `.ssh`, not `.shh`. 2) Have you configured public key access to Github? If not, use the `https://` URL ~ https://github.com/Ashe-EG/Prework-Study-Guide.git

Comment: `.shh` is very suspect. Did you accidentally type `.shh` instead of `.ssh` in your `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: Thank you for your reply's. it seem the issue was my typo of shh instead of ssh